# CSS Ul li navigation issue: Can't get correct result

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Trying to get following result when I hover

[image]

for markup below

```
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Current Month</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Current Week</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Previous Month</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Previous Week</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Next Month</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Next Week</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Team Calendar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Private Calendar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Can't figure out solution using CSS3 border-radius. Any suggestions?

## Update

Please don't post dotted lists. I need solution for arrowed list.

It's not same thing: when you use arrow, you need to set it as `background-image` of `li`.

There is another way, to set arrow as a bullet picture, but this time you have no way to control gap between arrow and link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
li:hover {
  background-color:#e4e4e4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEzxP/)

**EDIT**

If you want to use arrows instead, just use the `:before` pseudo element.

```
ul {
     list-style-type:none;
}    

li {

    padding:5px;
}

li:hover {

      width:100px;
      background-color:#e4e4e4;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
      border-radius: 5px; 

    }


li:before {
    content:"> ";

}
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEzxP/1/)

Just replace the `>` with your image.

**EDIT 2**

To have the background only over the text, just add that style to the link instead of the `li` then.

http://jsfiddle.net/SEzxP/2/

**EDIT 3**

To use an image instead, just use `url()` after content

```
li:before {  content:url('http://www.nationalacademies.org/xpedio/groups/system/documents/webgraphics/na_right_arrow.gif') /* with class ModalCarrot ??*/
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEzxP/3/)

Comment: Updated question, please take a look

Comment: Look http://screencast.com/t/dUGVXjy6 arrow stays inside the hovered area. But I need it to be outside.

Comment: Fixed in edit 2, just add the style to the `a` instead of the `li`

Comment: how to use image ( for ex this url http://goo.gl/UrHgc2 ) instead of `content` ??

Comment: is that cross browser supported?

Comment: absolutely, just be careful with IE7 and before, but AFAIK there are shims for that http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent

Answer (score 3):

```
    <style>
        .my-list li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000;
    }


.my-list li a:hover
    {
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #e4e4e4;
    }

    .my-list li{
        list-style-image:url(http://www.nationalacademies.org/xpedio/groups/system/documents/webgraphics/na_right_arrow.gif)
    }
    </style>        




    <ul class="my-list">
         <!--Example of gap using whitespace-->
         <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Current Month</a></li>
         <!--Example of a gap using padding for finer control of desired gap-->
         <li><a style="padding-left:20px;" href="#">Current Week</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Previous Month</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Previous Week</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">And so on...</a></li>
      </ul>
```

See jsFiddle also: http://jsfiddle.net/KRaJN/3/

Comment: I know how to do it with dotted list. How about arrow?

Comment: Updated question, please take a look

Comment: Updated answer with a jsfiddle link too

Comment: And how to control the space between link and arrow. also arrow position to get result look like image? http://screencast.com/t/Mrx4yakf50CG

Comment: Also added two different examples of how you can control the gap between the link and the arrow

Comment: Brian, I really very thankfull. But my mission is to get maximum similiar result with image that I post. But really I can't get this result when I use arrow image as `list-style-image` . I tried all possible ways and last way was to use arrow image as background image of li. But in this time, hover filled arrow too

Comment: If you replace the arrow image I used with yours and matched the font-size and font type in .my-list li a{} class it will look exactly the same as your screen shot.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfEk3/1/)

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    background:#E6E6E6;
    border-left:3px solid rgb(0, 194, 255);
}
li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
li a:hover {
    border-radius:5px;
    background: #cacaca;
}
li:before {
    content:"►";
    font-size:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: how to use image ( for ex this url http://goo.gl/UrHgc2 ) instead of `content` ??

Comment: @heron check this out.. http://jsfiddle.net/jfEk3/2/ .. although I like using `content:"►";` much better.

Comment: is that cross browser supported?

Comment: @heron Yea, test it out!

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-left: 1px solid #4AFFFF;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li:before {
    content: " ";
    display:inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000000;
}

li a {
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This should be ezactly how you want it!

http://jsfiddle.net/2JJaW/

Comment: And this is without the use of an image

Comment: Nice solution, this is much better than mine.